# Create shape background programmatically for older APIs

Tags: android, layout, background, shapes

I have created a shape background but `setColor` function of this does not support older API (Older than Android Lollipop i.e Kitkat, ICS). Is there any other way by which I can achieve this.

This is my current code:

```
val shape = GradientDrawable()
            shape.shape = GradientDrawable.OVAL
            shape.setStroke(strokeWidth!!,strokeColor!!)
            shape.setColor(selectedColor!!)
            p0.imageView.background = shape
```

Comment: older API means, can you be more specific?

Comment: @KishoreJethava Older then LOLLYPOP i.e Kitkat,ICS

Comment: post more code like variables `strokeColor` and drawable XML file

Comment: `strokeColor` is a variable only

Comment: What exactly is not supported ? `GradientDrawable` does not have any limitation of API level .

Comment: @ADM setColor of gradientDrawable supports API >21

Comment: @RajatMittal Did you find a solution, you can check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are two `setColor` method for `GradientDrawable`

First, *added in API level 1*

> public void setColor (int argb)

Second, *added in API level 21*

> public void setColor (ColorStateList colorStateList)

Solution!!

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    shape.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent)) // your selectedColor
  }else {
    shape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D81B60")) // your selectedColor
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kishore Thank you for your response but sadly it didn't work. So i tried using `shapeDrawable` and booyah!

```
            val oval = ShapeDrawable(OvalShape())
            oval.paint.color = selectedColor!!
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                p0.imageView.background = oval
            }
```